# How To Start Second tab's Content By View pager Adaptor android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

i am Suffering In Little problem .My Second Tab Of Fragment Is Not Performing The Task
my first tab is working 
i m using View Page Adapter for Tab 
[Here Is Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/)  same way of this tutorial i used 
but my second tab showing nothing

please help me ..
i will appreciate your suggestion
thanks in adavance

here is my view page adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String titles[] = new String[] { "Friends Request", "FriendsList" };

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 0:
            MyFriendsList fragmenttab1 = new MyFriendsList();
            return fragmenttab1;

            // Open Friendlist.java
        case 1:
            FriendsList fragmenttab2 = new FriendsList();
            return fragmenttab2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

in this my first tab of myfriendlist is working but Why Second tab Is not Calling It show blank page in frienlist

please help me

Comment: FriendsList fragmenttab2 = new FriendsList(); Post The fragment

Comment: ok I Updated Fragment Two....

Comment: Naveen I solved it was My Mistake ..When U said To Post Fragmnet TO then i saw My Mistake..thnxxxx

Comment: any more than mail me on my mail id

Comment: thnku bro ...but where is ur ..i havnt urs.id.neither on profile